# Can I send Intent to another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I m creating an app which opens another app in the background and my first app will be sending some string as a data to another app, so can I send Intents to another app's like we usually send intents to other classes containing data?

If we can then how can I send it?

Comment: You need to search first. I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2780475/1405983

Comment: question lacks originality. Please Google first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can send Intent to another app like we send to other classes with passing data as a string so you can see it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398799/trying-to-send-intent-to-other-app-error-securityexception-permission-denial/20284569#20284569)

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can send the intent to any app you like but its upto the receiving application to handle it.
Few apps may crash receiving it.

**The way**

Make an intent

```
Intent i=new Intent(yourContext,Activity_to_which_you_to_send.class);
```

**Put some data-if you want to**

```
i.putExtraString("key","value");

or put using a bundle
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString(key,boolean_value);
b.putBoolean(key,boolean_value)
```

**Starting the activity**

```
startActivity(i);
```

**Set the package of the app**

```
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

**Example**

if you want to find out the main Activity of an app

go to command line
type `adb shell pm -lf`

pick any one and try it by passing as a second argument to the intent constructor defined above and then call startActivity method.

hope it helps you.

Comment: its opening an activity and bringing it up in front but I want to open in background

Comment: Its an activity so it will open.

Comment: oh so is there any other way to open it in background?

Comment: You can send a broadcast then but you'll have to find that broadcast which requires more work.It will depend on the broadcast to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(name,yourString);
try{
     startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception ActivityNotFoundException){
     ActivityNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use this code to send an intent to another app and specify the name value and string in putExtra function.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. "App" is not so well defined on Android, it's a loose term. Intents are used to start an Activity, among other things.