# Intent recieved from action send generates SecurityException on URI

Tags: android, android-intent, securityexception

I'm trying to accept images with my app to send them to a server. Setting up the intent filter was easy enough and that works like a charm. The thing i can't seem to figure out is the way i need to retrieve the file path from the uri in the intent.

I receive intents on my activity with this filter

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/gif" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

By trying to process the uri to get the file path I get this error by calling takePersistableUriPermission(uri, modeFlags):

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10098 and Uri 0 @ content://media/external/images/media/124
```

The logic I use works for requesting images with an intent from inside my app, but receiving an intent from outside the app generates the error.

for Kitkat and above:

```
   final int flags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
   final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
   getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flags);
   String id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1]; 
   Cursor imageCursor = context.managedQuery(getStorageUri(), imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, null);
```

Comment: Are you getting this error in Android 6.0 and above ?

Comment: because you set android:exported="false" which mean that other process cannot access this Activity. So you set it to true and do the same it will not crash

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya no kitkat and above, just tested to be sure.

Comment: please look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414352/how-to-persist-permission-in-android-api-19-kitkat)

Comment: @DaminiMehra I've added android:exported="true" to the activity that has the mentioned intent-filter but nothing changed

Comment: look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398799/trying-to-send-intent-to-other-app-error-securityexception-permission-denial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing i can't seem to figure out is the way i need to retrieve the file path from the uri in the intent.

There is no "file path from the uri". A `Uri` is not a file.

> By trying to proses the uri to get the file path I get this error by calling takePersistableUriPermission(uri, modeFlags):

That just means that you cannot use the `Uri` once your process ends.

> for Kitkat and above:

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is not obligated to return you some `Uri` that can be processed using that code.

To consume the content identified by the `Uri`, [use `openInputStream()` on your `ContentResolver`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. for one, i am aware that the URI does not contain the file path, and therefore i need to process it to get the file path. I'm using an intent filter here that will receive an intent from another app that sends that content, not `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with start activity for result.

Comment: @SjoerdvGestel: "and therefore i need to process it to get the file path" -- you cannot "process it to get the file path", other than perhaps using `openInputStream()` to copy the content to some file that you control. There is no requirement for the user to pick a piece of content that you can access via the filesystem. The content could be on internal storage of another app, or on removable storage, or in a BLOB column of another app's database, or in "the cloud" that needs to be downloaded by the other app.

Comment: @SjoerdvGestel: Similarly, there is no requirement for a third-party app to grant you persistable permissions to that `Uri`. That is up to the other app to offer; you cannot force developers to offer it, short of using heavy weaponry.

Comment: thanks! i've compaired the uri's from booth inside my app and from the intent filter and there differen. thats the issue i thought booth would be the same.

Comment: yep getActivity().getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, flags); is not needed at all